# 'str' object has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: jquery, django

I try to update some data using Django form and ajax, the issue is the form does not accept 'POST['dat'], and I don't know why ?? any solution

jquery :

```
 $.ajax({ 
            headers: {
               
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
              data: {'dat' : $('#form-one').serialize(),'id':id}, 
              type: 'POST', 
              url: '/commande/update2post/', 
              success: function(response) { 
                $.ajax({ 
            headers: {
               
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
  });
```

views.py :

```
def update2post(request):
    

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
        print(request.POST['id'])
        print(request.POST.get('id'))
        commande = get_object_or_404(Commande, id=request.POST['id'])
        das = request.POST['dat']
       
        form = Commande_Form2(data=request.POST['dat'],instance=commande)// the issue ...
        if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
```

forms.py

```
class Commande_Form2(forms.ModelForm):
    Date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    Date_validation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Commande
        fields = ('Date','Client','Numero_commande','Montant_HT','Montant_TVA','Montant_TTC','Type_Service','validation','Date_validation')
```

Comment: Could you share the complete error which you getting?

Comment: this error : File "/home/juba/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' !!

Comment: what does your Commande_Form2 looks like ?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Is there any reason you are assigning all of the form data to a serialized dictionary element instead of just passing the whole form to POST with "id" as a hidden field? Just seems the way you are doing it is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: yeah , i going to update two forms at the same time, the second one is a formset , but i am stuck with the first form

Comment: You use form prefixes when you have multiple forms in a request. You should always pass the full POST object to each form

Comment: its not one request , i trigger the second request after the success of the first ajax request , two ajax request , one after another